# JWT::DecodeError (No verification key available)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

this is my sessions controller code

```
def respond_to_on_destroy

    jwt_payload = JWT.decode(request.headers['Authorization'].split(' ')[1], 
    Rails.application.credentials.fetch(:secret_key_base)).first
    
    current_user = User.find(jwt_payload['sub'])
    
    if current_user
      debugger
      return render json: {
        status: 200, message: 'signed out successfully'
      }
    else
      return render json: {
        status: 401, message: 'user has no active session'
      }
    end
  end
```

this is my devise.rb file code

```
config.jwt do |jwt|
    jwt.secret = Rails.application.credentials.fetch(:secret_key_base)
    jwt.dispatch_requests = [
      ['POST', %r{^/users/sign_in$}]
    ]
    jwt.revocation_requests = [
      ['DELETE', %r{^/users/sign_out}]
    ]
    jwt.expiration_time = 120.minutes.to_i
 end
```

i am devise and devise-jwt and i am using rails 7 version

Answer (score 1):

Try insert in your Gemfile:

> gem 'warden-jwt_auth', '~> 0.6.0'

Comment: Thanks! 0.7.0 broke. Downgrading worked!